# Denied boarding on my China Eastern flight to Bangkok Thailand

Tags: air-travel

I was to fly to Bangkok, Thailand, via Nanjing, China, on a China Eastern flight from Vancouver. However since I am traveling using a Canadian Refugee travel document I was denied boarding by the agents saying that I need a Chinese transit visa. My transit time in Nanjing was for 7 and a half hours. What the airline right to deny me boarding? What options do I have? Thanks.

Comment: You haven't posted your nationality, which may be relevant. Nationals of certain middle East countries and some Asian countries are not eligible for transit without visa (TWOV). You can find more details [here](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/free-transit-24hour.htm).    There may also be additional requirements for those travelling on refugee documents.